# convert string to specific datetime format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

String

```
"2011-05-19 10:30:14"
```

To

```
Thu May 19 10:30:14 UTC 2011
```

How can I convert specific string to this Date format ?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

```
require 'date'

date = DateTime.parse("2011-05-19 10:30:14")
formatted_date = date.strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
```

See [strftime()](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) for more information about formatting dates.

Answer (score 35):

`"2011-05-19 10:30:14".to_time`

Comment: I am getting NoMethodError...which modules are you loading?

Comment: @mrek this method is defined in rails or more specifically activesupport's String extension. You can ```require 'active_support/core_ext/string'``` to get it. See http://apidock.com/rails/String/to_time

Comment: Although this might answer the question, please don't post code-only answers.

Answer (score 17):

No need to apply anything. Just add this code at the end of variable to which date is assigned. For example

```
   @todaydate = "2011-05-19 10:30:14"
   @todaytime.to_time.strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
```

You will get proper format as you like. You can check this at Rails Console

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.4)
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > todaytime = "2011-05-19 10:30:14"
 => "2011-05-19 10:30:14" 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > todaytime
 => "2011-05-19 10:30:14" 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :003 > todaytime.to_time
 => 2011-05-19 10:30:14 UTC
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :008 > todaytime.to_time.strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
 => "Thu May 19 10:30:14 UTC 2011"
```

Try '[date_format](https://github.com/rpatil/date_format)' gem to show date in different format.

Answer (score 11):

More formats:

```
 require 'date'

 date = "01/07/2016 09:17AM"
 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%A, %b %d")
 #=> Friday, Jul 01

 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
 #=> 07/01/2016

 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%m-%e-%y %H:%M")
 #=> 07- 1-16 09:17

 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%b %e")
 #=> Jul  1

 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%l:%M %p")
 #=>  9:17 AM

 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%B %Y")
 #=> July 2016
 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%b %d, %Y")
 #=> Jul 01, 2016
 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%a, %e %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
 #=> Fri,  1 Jul 2016 09:17:00 +0200
 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%l:%M:%S%z")
 #=> 2016-07-01T 9:17:00+0200
 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
 #=> 09:17:00 AM
 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
 #=> 09:17:00
 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%e %b %Y %H:%M:%S%p")
 #=>  1 Jul 2016 09:17:00AM
 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%d.%m.%y")
 #=> 01.07.16
 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%A, %d %b %Y %l:%M %p")
 #=> Friday, 01 Jul 2016  9:17 AM
```

Answer (score 5):

This another helpful code:

```
"2011-05-19 10:30:14".to_datetime.strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `DATE_FORMAT` from [Date Conversions](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Date/Conversions.html):

In your initializer:

```
DateTime::DATE_FORMATS[:my_date_format] = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"
```

In your view:

```
date = DateTime.parse("2011-05-19 10:30:14")
date.to_formatted_s(:my_date_format)
date.to_s(:my_date_format)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  <%= string_to_datetime("2011-05-19 10:30:14") %>

  def string_to_datetime(string,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    DateTime.strptime(string, format).to_time unless string.blank?
  end
```