# Converting String to Datetime Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

I'm using LazyHighCharts and trying to convert json data to display only the last 24hrs, I'm having some troubles converting the date and time ("2014-06-16 16:00:00") to milliseconds.

data structure

```
{"status": "ok", "data": [{"2014-06-16 16:00:00": 24.2},{"2014-06-17 12:00:00": 30.2},{"2014-06-18 17:00:00": 42.9}]} etc
```

Controller

```
@data = JSON.parse(open(@temperature.url).read)

dates = []
temps = []

@data['data'].each do |data|
 dates << data.keys
 temps << data.values
end 

datetime = dates.each do |d| DateTime.parse(d).to_i end

@graph = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
 f.chart(:height => '400')
 f.yAxis [:title => {:text => "Temperature", :margin => 20, style: { color: '#333'}}]
 f.series(:pointInterval => 1.hour, :pointStart => 30.day.ago, :type => 'area', :name => '24hrs', :data => [[datetime, temps]])
 f.options[:xAxis] = { :minTickInterval => 24 * 3600 * 1000, :type => "datetime", :dateTimeLabelFormats => { day: "%b %e"}, :title => { :text => nil }, :labels => { :enabled => true } }
end
```

Answer (score 15):

You need to covert sstring to dateTime as the first, 
Use this code:

```
DateTime.parse("2011-05-19 10:30:14").strftime('%Q')
```

Or this code:

```
"2014-06-16 16:00:00".to_datetime.strftime('%Q')
```

So you can convert array of strings of dates as the following:

```
dates.map!{|d| d.to_datetime.strftime('%Q')}
```

Helper links: [link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001883/ruby-convert-datetime-to-milliseconds), [link-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070957/convert-string-to-specific-datetime-format)

Comment: Thanks guys, I understand that format, but not sure how I implement it using the data.keys from the json? Say 'dates.to_datetime.strftime('%Q')' gives me 'undefined method `to_datetime' for #<Array:0x007fef71dd39d0>'

Comment: use this code `dates.map!{|d| d.to_datetime.strftime('%Q')}`

Comment: Cheers... getting "undefined method `to_datetime' for ["2014-08-12 10:00:00"]:Array" error.

Comment: okay, try another code `dates.map!{|d| DateTime.parse(d).strftime('%Q')}`, but the first code is worked with me on rails console :)

Comment: Same issue. Thanks for trying. Not sure what the issues is here.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails you can convert a properly formatted string to milliseconds with:

```
"2014-06-16 16:00:00".to_datetime.strftime('%Q')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Activesupport [`String#in_time_zone`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-in_time_zone)

> in_time_zone(zone = ::Time.zone)Link Converts String to a TimeWithZone
> in the current zone if Time.zone or Time.zone_default is set,
> otherwise converts String to a Time via String#to_time