# Converting datetime string into single unit of time (like seconds) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datetime

I am having a lot of trouble converting a timestamp from Rails into something I can use in my Javascript.

Specifically, I have an alert set up to show the time of an event happening, and it produces a string like this: `2016-02-18T23:07:00.000-08:00`. What's weird is that doesn't look like a UTC string to me (as this [answer outlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680025/converting-utc-string-to-epoch-time-in-javascript)), and I can't figure out what time format that is.

I have tried [using this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070957/convert-string-to-specific-datetime-format):

```
  var t = "2016-02-18T23:07:00.000-08:00"
  var u = t.to_time
```

But that returns "undefined." Ideally, I'd like to convert this string in Javascript to seconds or milliseconds. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var t = "2016-02-18T23:07:00.000-08:00"
var u = Date.parse(t);
```

Comment: Just tried the `Date.parse`, and unfortunately it is returning NaN. Is it possible that string is not parseable?

Comment: I was tried it in here : https://jsfiddle.net/8ra4j287/   .I think you should convert to Int before calculate. `var sec = Number(u);`

Comment: Gave it a shot. `var sec = Number(u)` returned NaN as well. I'll investigate and report back if I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Moment.js:

```
moment('2016-02-18T23:07:00.000-08:00').format('LLL');
```

Returns:

> February 19, 2016 8:07 AM

Or just a timestamp:

```
Date.parse('2016-02-18T23:07:00.000-08:00');
```

Works fine

https://momentjs.com